# Multiple applications accessing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is my first post and am very new to MS SQL Server.  We have MS SQL Server running on an existing server. We have a software application that is utilizing the SQL Server as its back-end.

We are purchasing another software application that requires MS SQL Server.  Can we utilize the same SQL Server for this new application or do we need to purchase new SQL server software and install on new server?

Both applications will use the same version of SQL Server.

Comment: What does the "another software application" vendor say?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on a few things.

1. **SQL version**. Will the new application run on the same version of SQL as the existing application?
2. **Security**. Are you comfortable having the same people possess server-wide permissions to both applications?
3. **Performance**. Are you comfortable with a runaway query in one application possibly affecting the performance of the other application?
4. **Maintenance**. Are you comfortable with the idea of any maintenance that requires a server reboot or a SQL service restart taking both applications out of commission at the same time?
5. **Vendor support**. Do the vendors of each application support having them co-located on a server with other applications? (Just because the vendor doesn't like it, doesn't mean you can't make it work. But if you don't follow the vendor's requirements, you run the risk of them refusing to help you when something goes wrong.)